# PhoneGap FileTransfer and Server side scripting

Tags: php, javascript, ios, cordova, file-transfer

I'm stucked with this for the whole day, the JavaScipt code seems fine. But in the output i get this:

```
2012-09-25 15:09:57.584 ViviJesolo[13863:c07] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
2012-09-25 15:09:57.586 ViviJesolo[13863:c07] [INFO] Code = 200
2012-09-25 15:09:57.586 ViviJesolo[13863:c07] [INFO] Response = Array%0A(%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bfile%5D%20=%3E%20Array%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bname%5D%20=%3E%20cdv_photo_027.jpg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Btype%5D%20=%3E%20image/jpg%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Btmp_name%5D%20=%3E%20/tmp/php4i7HAa%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Berror%5D%20=%3E%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bsize%5D%20=%3E%202340%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0A%0A)%0A
2012-09-25 15:09:57.587 ViviJesolo[13863:c07] [INFO] Sent = 2548
```

My server side script is:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/httpdocs/upload/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

I've checked the permissions and it's ok, but i can't see the uploaded file.
What could be the problem?

Edit: I'm uploading the image using FileTransfer object like this:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) 
{
 var options = new FileUploadOptions(); 
 options.fileKey="file"; 
 options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 options.mimeType="image/jpg";
 var params = new Object();
 params.headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;
 var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "site.com/upload.php";, win, fail, options); 
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry for non defined question. I cant see the uploaded file.
The ouput code is 200, means successful but the image is nowhere.

Comment: From where and how are you uploading the image?

Comment: I'm uploading the image using FileTransfer object:
    `function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpg";
    
    var params = new Object();
    params.headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};
    
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://www.site.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be you had the destination file path wrong, try appending your path to the document root, like this:

```
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/httpdocs/upload/".$new_image_name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
```

Comment: tried, but still nothing. should be the uploaded image stay in the tmp folder, if it's not moved?

Comment: How did you checked permission? can you paste the output of "ls -l" while inside 'httpdocs' folder ?

Comment: Using ftp client. i dont have terminal access to the server.

Comment: No sign of the file on server, everthing is done with success on the client side. Strange...

Comment: when you are inside the 'httpdocs' folder in your ftp client, what permissions and what owner is displayed for the 'upload' entry ?

Comment: You need to make sure the 'upload' entry has write permission for ALL(OTHER) users. Check for that.

Comment: yep, its 777.
Files are small so i dont think it would be max size problem.

Comment: it works, i needed to use just /upload/, without httpdocs.
Thanks man!!